# How to run specflow API test on VSTS pipeline

Tags: c#, azure, automation, specflow

Im able to build and install the packages but I dont really know what command to give to run the test cases, I'm new to devops, can I please get a hint, im using Xunit and have 4 features for my API testing

Answer (score 1):

From the SpecFlow+ Runner Documentation (https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/SpecFlowPlus-and-TFS-VSTS/)

1. Click on Add build step to add a new step to the build definition.
   Click on Test in the list of categories and click on Add next to
   "Visual Studio Test".
2. Configure the build step as follows:
   Enter the path to your Test Assembly (the DLL containing your compiled specifications project with the test bindings).
3. Save your changes.

So it should be no more to add a VSTest task and configure the test assembly name.